# Knex query event logs to winston file.

Tags: javascript, knex.js

I would like save all knex query event to winston file. I found somthing like this
http://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-Events . Its work good for my but now i have to add

```
 .on('query-response', function(response, obj, builder)...
```

for each knex query.

I would like add one global function for all qnex query. It is possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can export your `knex` object from a separate `dbConnection` file and import it in other file where you need. In your `dbConnection` file add event listener to `knex`. Like here:
In your `dbConnection` file write this:

```
const knex = require('knex')({ 
    //Your db configuration here
});

knex.on('query', console.log);

module.exports = knex;
```

In your other file require it and use it.

```
const knex = require('/dbConnection');
```

Comment: but this approach is on console.log not on winston